# Upload PostgreSQL Database to AWS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

I have a PostgreSQL database . How I can migrate this to Amazon Web Service RDS??

I don't understand how to do it. Is it using Database Migration Service on AWS?

Comment: yes - its one of the most popular ways

Comment: Can Database Migration Service export local database to Amazon RDS?

Answer (score 5):

You can use AWS Database Migration Service, but that seems like an overkill if you migrate from PostgreSQL to PostgreSQL. Database Migration Service allows data migration between different RDBMS and even between NoSQL databases and RDBMS.

Just dump your database with `pg_dump` and restore it to RDS instance with `pg_restore`.

Comment: I have dumped my database. How do I can restore it with pg_restore on RDS Instance?